# I'm testing mail sending with php. But it does not work when customer apply my contact with YAHOO

Tags: php, email

The headers work properly when I test with other mail like Gmail or Hotmail.  But it does not work with **Yahoo**.

```
$headers = "From: $Itm_2 $Itm_3 <someone@yahoo.com>" . "\r\n";  
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

//Send Mail to Owner
@mail($owner_email,"Website Contact From $Itm_2 $Itm_3",$UserData,$headers);
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking, but there's a decent chance the receiving server is deliberately filtering out your mail, either because you're using PHP to mail, or because your server isn't configured to be trustworthy enough.

Comment: i mean the owner will not get the message if user using their yahoo mail to contact owner thought website contact form

Comment: There's all kinds of spam filtering mechanisms. Unless you investigate your SMTP server setup and logs, you'll never find out. The shown code excerpt isn't overly relevant.